# Bootstrap wont get 4 DIVs in one row

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, css

So guys my questions says I am trying to make **4 DIV's** being in the same line/row however.

```
          Product      Company   (middle)      Languages    DIV4
          text...      text...                 text...      text...
          text...      text...                 text...      text...
```

it should look something like that...   .I hope you do understand what i mean!

so this is my code:    `

```
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">

                 <div class="col-md-4">
                            <h2>Product</h2>
                            <li> <a href="templates.php">Templates</a></li> 
                            <li> <a href="pricing.php">Pricing</a></li>
                </div>

                 <div class="col-md-4">
                            <h2>Company</h2>
                            <li><a href="aboutus.php">About Us</a></li>
                            <li><a href="contact.php">Contact us</a></li>
                            <li><a href="terms.php">Terms of Servise</a></li>
                            <li><a href="policy.php">Privacy policy</a></li>
                </div>          

                 <div class="col-md-4">
                            <h2>Language</h2>
                            <li><a href="login.php">Englisch</a></li>
                            <li><a href="login.php">German</a></li>
                            <li><a href="login.php">Srpski</a></li>
                </div>          

                 <div class="col-md-4">
                            <li><a href="login.php">facebook</a></li>
                            <li><a href="login.php">kaaa</a></li>
                            <li><a href="login.php">kaaa</a></li>
                </div>          

            </div>
        </div>
```

Comment: use col-md-3 instead of col-md-4

Comment: make .row{display:flex} it should work or use display:inline-block

Comment: you also need ul for those li's

Comment: Display flex worked for me thanks mate

Comment: Solved and explained in my answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First make sure that your markup is valid. E.g. for your `li` tags the `ul` tag was missing.

If you want to display 4 divs, you need the class `col-md-3` instead of `col-md-4`. Bootstrap is using a grid system with a default column count of 12. If you need 4 columns you have to use 12/4 = 3 meaning `col-md-3`.

The `md` stands for medium. So for small devices, the columns break and are displayed on top of each other. Watch the following example in fullscreen, to see the columns standing next to each other.

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <h2>Product</h2>
            <ul>
                <li> <a href="templates.php">Templates</a></li> 
                <li> <a href="pricing.php">Pricing</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <h2>Company</h2>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="aboutus.php">About Us</a></li>
                <li><a href="contact.php">Contact us</a></li>
                <li><a href="terms.php">Terms of Servise</a></li>
                <li><a href="policy.php">Privacy policy</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>          
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <h2>Language</h2>
            <ul>
                <li><a href="login.php">Englisch</a></li>
                <li><a href="login.php">German</a></li>
                <li><a href="login.php">Srpski</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>          
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="login.php">facebook</a></li>
                <li><a href="login.php">kaaa</a></li>
                <li><a href="login.php">kaaa</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>          
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Ok, what exactly is wrong? How are the columns displayed?

Comment: They are in one row but from the top- to the bottom,they should be in an row from the left to the right

Comment: I think I ammissing something

Comment: Are you sure you have the bootstrap css applied?

Answer (score 2):

Could be a screen size issue and also sytax issue

1. Bootstrap only allows 12 columns per row, so each column needs "width" of 3, `col-md-3`
2. Then since the size is set to `md` the columns widths are set up for a medium size screen
3. With `col-xs-3` it will make the columns as small as they can go without overflowing to the next row

```html
<!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">


<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3">
      <h2>Product</h2>
      <ul>
        <li> <a href="templates.php">Templates</a>
        </li>
        <li> <a href="pricing.php">Pricing</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3">
      <h2>Company</h2>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="aboutus.php">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="contact.php">Contact us</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="terms.php">Terms of Servise</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="policy.php">Privacy policy</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3">
      <h2>Language</h2>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="login.php">Englisch</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="login.php">German</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="login.php">Srpski</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-3">
      <h2>Share</h2>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="login.php">facebook</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="login.php">kaaa</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="login.php">kaaa</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

check this snippet

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h2>Product</h2>
      <ul>
        <li> <a href="templates.php">Templates</a>
        </li>
        <li> <a href="pricing.php">Pricing</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h2>Company</h2>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="aboutus.php">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="contact.php">Contact us</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="terms.php">Terms of Servise</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="policy.php">Privacy policy</a>
        </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">

      <h2>Language</h2>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="login.php">Englisch</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="login.php">German</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="login.php">Srpski</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>

    <div class="col-md-4">
      <h2>div4</h2>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="login.php">facebook</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="login.php">kaaa</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="login.php">kaaa</a>
        </li>

      </ul>
    </div>

  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps